# CYGWIN: Variables in memory spontaneously changing values

Tags: c++, gdb, cygwin

Some of my variables change values seemingly unjustifiably when I change other variables in my c++ code. I've used gdb to hardware watch the memory in question and it will occur even when I just cout << "bla";

If anybody could offer ANY suggestions as how to fix this, it would be greatly appreciated! I'm stumped!

When I run the sample max memory program provided in the cygwin docs, I am told I have 1.5 GB of available RAM (which should easily be enough for the scope of this program).

Comment: [First rule of programming: it's always your fault](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html). Please post some example code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: It's hard for anyone to provide assistance if you dont post the code you're using =]

Comment: If you set gdb to hardware break on the value changing, what's changing the variable?  Are you debugging an optimized build (the compiler will 'reuse' memory for variables if it can and wants to)?

Comment: @Michael Burr Arbitrary lines such as cout << "bla"; are changing the variable. If I comment out said line, the next command will cause the variable to change value.

Comment: @mdec My code is a bit of a mess from all of my attempts at fixing it, but also I wouldn't expect anybody to want to dig through it all!

Comment: Are you compiling with the `-g -O0` flags? You need to; if the optimizer is on, it can do things that confuse gdb such as register coloring or combining variables that have non-overlapping lifetimes. I think there's a flag like `-fomit-frame-pointer` that makes baby gdb cry, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause of a variable "spontaneously" changing value is a buffer overflow. The next most likely cause is heap corruption (or using memory after it has been `free()`d or `delete`d (aka dangling memory)).

You didn't say whether the variables that change are global, heap allocated, or local. I am guessing heap allocated, in which case the dangling theory is the most likely one -- anything that can allocate memory legitimately (e.g. `cout`) could grab and modify the memory you have released via `free` or `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to check for memory errors in your code?

Comment: Will valgrind run on Windows (Cygwin)?

Comment: If it does, I'll be honest and say I have no idea about how to make it work. I'm a Windows person who can occasionally jump over to Cygwin to write the occasional C++ and fortran code. So no, I haven't tried valgrind (though it looks immensely useful!)

Comment: No Valgrind, but there's the dmalloc library of error-checking heap routines.

Comment: No need to torture yourself trying to make valgrind work on Windows if it does not do so easily. Just spin up a virtual machine running Linux and try your code there.